# Percent-escapes in URL converted to latin charset on IIS 8.5

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, joomla, utf-8

After migrating to a new Windows IIS 8.5 server requests are not passed through as UTF-8 characters but single byte latin characters.

UTF-8 characters are needed in order to use pretty or SEO friendly URL's on our WordPress and Joomla installations.

From PHP a `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` looks like this

```
/ p r e s s e / p r  ø  v e s i d e
2f7072657373652f7072 f8 766573696465
```

In the web.config file in the web server root we have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="aspnet:UseLegacyRequestUrlGeneration" value="true" />
   </appSettings>
   <system.web>
      <globalization
         requestEncoding="utf-8"
         responseEncoding="utf-8"
         culture="da-DK"
         uiCulture="da-DK" />
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
   ...
   <system.webServer>
<configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the following change to the registry fixed the problem

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\w3svc\Parameters /v FastCGIUtf8ServerVariables /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d REQUEST_URI\0PATH_INFO
```

Seems the Microsoft [KB2277918](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2277918) hot-fix from IIS 7.5 is rolled into IIS 8.5

After applying the registry changes `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` looks like this in PHP

```
/ p r e s s e / p r  Ã ¸  v e s i d e
2f7072657373652f7072 c3b8 766573696465
```

The bytes `C3` `B8` being the danish letter 'ø'.